# WSO2 APIM 1.10: configure sequences via Publisher UI

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

where is the UI for selecting the sequence for in/out/fault in publisher app.
In Version 1.7 is a checkbox in the "Manage"-Tab[1], but in the current version 1.10 this checkbox is missing. 
I can't find a description in the current documentation[2], how can I configure sequences for single APIs? Or must I edit the API via carbon-registry?

Regards

Marty

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Managing+APIs

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-Sequences

Answer (score 0):

I found the configuration option. It is in the "Implement"-Tab.

See "Message Mediation Policies" -> https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Change+the+Default+Mediation+Flow+of+API+Requests

Answer (score 0):

We have moved this to Implementation Tab inside "Enable Message Mediation" and, with API Manager 1.10, you can upload your own Message Mediation Policies through Publisher UI.

For more information, check [Adding Mediation Extensions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions)